# Comparing instance variables from two objects

Tags: java

I need help implementing a function in which I have to compare the instance variables of a calling object and a parameter object. My classmate said I could call the compareTo() function but I feel there is an easier way to implement this.

I had to overload the constructor earlier which would be a copy of the Money object by copying the value of each instance variable from the parameter object to the instance variable of the new object, which I think I implemented correctly, but I'm not sure if that is the problem or not.

My output is "$10.02 does not equal $10.02" which isn't make sense to me on why it's happening. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
/**
 This class represents nonnegative amounts of money.
 */

public class Money
{
    // The number of dollars
    private long dollars;

    // The number of cents
    private long cents;

    /**
     Constructor
     @param amount The amount in decimal format.
     */

    public Money(double amount)
    {
        if (amount < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Negative amounts " +
                    "of money are not allowed.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            long allCents = Math.round(amount * 100);
            dollars = allCents / 100;
            cents = allCents % 100;
        }
    }

    // ADD LINES FOR TASK #1 HERE
    // Document and write a copy constructor
    // Creating a copy of the Money constructor
    public Money(Money obj) {
        dollars = obj.dollars;
        cents = obj.cents;
    }

    /**
     The add method
     @param otherAmount The amount of money to add.
     @return The sum of the calling Money object
     and the parameter Money object.
     */

    public Money add(Money otherAmount)
    {
        Money sum = new Money(0);

        sum.cents = this.cents + otherAmount.cents;

        long carryDollars = sum.cents / 100;

        sum.cents = sum.cents % 100;

        sum.dollars = this.dollars +
                otherAmount.dollars +
                carryDollars;

        return sum;
    }

    /**
     The subtract method
     @param amount The amount of money to subtract.
     @return The difference between the calling Money
     object and the parameter Money object.
     */

    public Money subtract (Money amount)
    {
        Money difference = new Money(0);

        if (this.cents < amount.cents)
        {
            this.dollars = this.dollars - 1;
            this.cents = this.cents + 100;
        }

        difference.dollars = this.dollars - amount.dollars;
        difference.cents = this.cents - amount.cents;

        return difference;
    }

    /**
     The compareTo method
     @param amount The amount of money to compare against.
     @return -1 if the dollars and the cents of the
     calling object are less than the dollars and
     the cents of the parameter object.
     0 if the dollars and the cents of the calling
     object are equal to the dollars and cents of
     the parameter object.
     1 if the dollars and the cents of the calling
     object are more than the dollars and the
     cents of the parameter object.
     */

    public int compareTo(Money amount)
    {
        int value;

        if(this.dollars < amount.dollars)
            value = -1;
        else if (this.dollars > amount.dollars)
            value = 1;
        else if (this.cents < amount.cents)
            value = -1;
        else if (this.cents > amount.cents)
            value = 1;
        else
            value = 0;

        return value;
    }

    // ADD LINES FOR TASK #2 HERE
    // Document and write an equals method
    // Document and write a toString method

    // Writing the equals method
    public boolean equals(Money obj) {
        return (this.dollars == obj.dollars && this.cents == obj.cents);
    }

    // Writing the toString method
    public String toString() {
        if (this.cents < 10) {
            return "$" + this.dollars + ".0" + this.cents;
        }
        else {
            return "$" + this.dollars + "." + this.cents;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hint: _Always_ use `@Override` for `equals`, and you must override `hashCode` when you override `equals`.

Comment: He is right. If you don't `@override`, it uses Java's own method.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic-When I tried implementing Override for hashCode, how exactly do I implement that? I tried using public long hashCode() and returning this.dollars but I get an error stating 'hashCode()' in 'Money' clashes with 'hashCode()' in 'java.lang.Object'; attempting to use incompatible return type. I'm not sure how I go on implementing hashCode

Comment: I don't know if Java has changed since Java 8 but Override annotation was not a condition to override a method. It should still be used anyway to prevent this classic scenario where a person thinks they have overridden a method but they actually didn't and their IDE would have probably giving them an error if they had the method annotated with Override,

Comment: @AerysS Can you explain what you meant by "*If you don't @override, it uses Java's own method*"? I may be misunderstanding you, but for now it sounds like you claim that without `@Override` annotation method *can't be overriding other one* which is not true. `@Override` annotation doesn't enable overriding, but tells compile to check *if* we are overriding other method or not. If we are compiler will not complain, but if I are not (like in case of OP code since expected parameter type is `Object`, not `Money`) compiler will inform us about it which will save us some debugging time later.

Answer (score 0):

The proper signature of the `equals` method is `boolean equals(Object o)`; this is already in java.lang.Object, therefore, all objects have it.

You made a completely different method which is not overriding this one at all. It just coincidentally also is named `equals`, but it is not the same method, because, well, that's how java works. The types have to match.

So, fix that. Check the type using e.g. `other.getClass() == Money.class`, if that's not the case, you can return `false`, if it is, you can cast `other` and continue from there.

A few other comments on code quality:

1. doubles are not precise; do not use them to represent money. Use `int` or `long`, and represent cents with them.
2. Calling `System.exit()` on errors is rather brutal. The proper move is `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative money not allowed");` (note that exception messages should not end in punctuation).
3. your code is most of the way there to say that a `Money` object can never change once made. Go all the way, make those fields `final`, and at that point your copy constructor is useless. There's no reason to ever make a copy - all your methods that 'change' things don't actually change things - they make a new money object already.